# Using "chmod -R 666 filename" does not give all files writing permissions

Tags: linux, sudo, root, chmod

I have been running as root in a Linux Virtual Machine to change permissions to a whole list of files within a directory. When I check the permissions after using `sudo chmod 666 -R /home/candidate/working/other_files`, all the files have read and write privileges besides one hidden file (highlighted in the image). I am not sure how I can make it so that file will also have write privileges when I specifically wrote the `chmod` command that should give all the files read and write privileges.

The file `..` does not have write permission for all other users after using `chmod`:

```
root@d3ac9495a31:/home/candidate/working# chmod -R 666 /home/candidate/working/other_files/
root@d3ac9495a31:/home/candidate/working# ls -la other_files
total 14108
drw-rw-rw- 1 root      root         4096 Feb 27  2018 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 candidate candidate    4096 Feb 27  2018 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root      root      4537584 Feb 27  2018 file1.html
drwxrwxr-x 1 root      root      1123786 Feb 27  2018 file2.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root      root      5747804 Feb 27  2018 file3.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root      root      3013094 Feb 27  2018 file4.html
```

Comment: `..` is the parent directory. It does not exist within `other_files`, but instead refers to `working` which you are not changing the permissions of.

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/44425), just copy the console text and paste here

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here

1. Technical. You have removed search permission (`x`) for the `other_files` directory (represented in the listing as `.`). This will cause problems when you try to list it, or access files in it. Fix with `chmod a+x other_files`
2. Convenience. You don't always need to specify a full filesystem path for `chmod`. Here, since you are already in `working` you could have used `chmod -R 666 other_files`. But see #1 as this is actually wrong - you should only be changing permissions of the files and not the directory too. So `chmod 666 other_files/*` would have been better and more correct.
3. Understanding. The `.` directory entry (see the leading `d` in the permissions block within `ls -l`) represents the current directory, in this case `other_files`. The `..` entry points to the parent directory, in this case `working`. Parent directories are typically excluded from recursive operations as otherwise you'd end up travelling up the filesystem tree as well as down.
4. Operational. Generally, you shouldn't really be working as `root` when you're in `candidate`'s home directory. Consider resetting the files' owner so that it's `candidate`, and then work as `candidate` instead of `root`. For starters, this will make it harder for you to break your system accidentally.

Comment: No need for `x` permissions to list the contents of a directory. You need it to access any file in it though, including retrieving their metadata (in that sense, you'd need `x` permission to get a useful long listing).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas consider `mkdir x; touch x/{1,2,3,4}; chmod 644 x`. For the comannd `ls x` (i.e. not a long listing) I get four errors such as `ls: cannot access 'x/1': Permission denied` followed by the otherwise usual result showing all four files. I suppose that if you allow `ls x 2>/dev/null` then listing it "works".

Comment: Which confirms that `ls` was able to list its contents and that it's the `lstat()` done on each file (you must have some alias for `ls` with some `-F` or `--color` option that requests metadata from each file) that fails, as you don't have *search* permission.